# What is the most efficient way to take down a Titan?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm playing in the Joker's Carnival combat challenge stage, which has a time limit. Once the top level has been reached, a Titan will spawn out of the gate. I've usually thought that pounding the ground (performing the rodeo shockwave move (by pressing the stun button)) three times is the fastest way to take down a Titan (reducing the riding time).

What method will (permanently) neutralize a Titan fastest?

How is this question different from [What is the procedure for taking down Titans?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/what-is-the-procedure-for-taking-down-titans) I am not asking simply how to take down a Titan, but which is the fastest way. I presume that to most (who browse this site anyway (because if a question like this threatens to be closed, it is unlikely players looking to achieve high-scores will find other such questions & answers on this site)), the questions seem the same because they don't care how they take down the Titan. But I explain that in the Joker's Carnival combat challenge stage, time is of the essence. Therefore it is important to know which, among all of the means by which to take down a Titan, is the most efficient way to take down a Titan, to conserve as much time as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the procedure for taking down Titans?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/what-is-the-procedure-for-taking-down-titans)

Answer (score 2):

Some not-so-precise measurements:

Charges: under 23.13 (seconds), from pre-control-loss to post-control-gain
Ride: under 21.73
Pounds: under 15.23

Meaning pounding three times seems to be the fastest way to end a Titan ride.
Though, the charges went diagonally across Joker's Carnival, it is not simple to prevent the Titan from charging directly away from an adjacent wall. The fastest ride of charges may be charging perpendicular to the long walls. One may also theorize that the duration of a ride-free-from-special-moves may differ depending on the number of turns and such maneuvers made.